# Split list into random sub lists and assign three randomised values to each element in sub lists

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the below code currently to split a list into two equal sub lists as below.

Group 1 = [2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 14, 15, 16]

Group 2 = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13]

```
import random

# Split list into two sub lists
#def sub_lists():

data = list(range(1, 17))
random.shuffle(data)
Group1, Group2 = sorted(data[:8]), sorted(data[8:])
print(Group1, Group2)

# assign randomised values to elements in each group
for i in Group1:
   Tasks = ['A', 'B','C']
   random.shuffle(Tasks)
   with open('Group1_allocation.txt', 'a') as f:
      f.write(f'{i} = {Tasks}\n')


for j in Group2:
   Tasks = ['A', 'B','C']
   random.shuffle(Tasks)
   with open('Group2_allocation.txt', 'a') as f:
      f.write(f'{j} = {Tasks}\n')
```

And then assign each element in the sub lists (Group1 and Group 2) three randomised values from a new list (Tasks) such that I get the following output in each fle.

Group1_allocation.txt

2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']

5 = ['B', 'A', 'C']

6 = ['C', 'A', 'B']

8 = ['B', 'A', 'C']

10 = ['C', 'B', 'A']

14 = ['B', 'C', 'A']

15 = ['A', 'C', 'B']

16 = ['C', 'A', 'B']

The script works, but contains repeated code. How could this be coded cleaner/better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with one less loop:

```
import random

data = list(range(1, 17))
random.shuffle(data)
l = len(data)

Tasks = ['A', 'B','C']
for i,d in enumerate(data):
    filename = 'Group{}_allocation.txt'.format(int(1 + i // (l / 2)))
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'{data[i]} = {Tasks}\n')
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried the code but it doesn't randomise the Tasks list for each element. Adding random.shuffle(Tasks) before the For Loop shuffles the list, but then all elements get the same shuffled Tasks (In same order)

Comment: ok so I see my mistake. I moved the shuffle inside the For Loop and now gets the same desired effect ! Thanks this code is much shorter than mine, and achieves the same result